# Cleaner/more efficient way to pull top 10% only

Tags: sql, rank

I'm creating a leaderboard to return just the top 10% revenue streams this quarter.  I've hacked together a solution with analytic functions but I feel like there's a simpler way.

The main fields are stream_ID, stream_rev, quarter, and timestamp (the table contains revenue whenever it happens, which can be multiple times a day)

Here's what I've done:

```
SELECT stream_ID,
       rev,
       rev_rank
       FROM(
       SELECT stream_ID,
              count(distinct stream_ID) OVER () as total_streams,
              sum(stream_rev) as rev,
              rank() OVER (ORDER BY sum(stream_rev) desc) AS rev_rank
        FROM mastertable
        WHERE quarter = "2019-Q4"
        GROUP BY stream_ID
        )
WHERE rev_rank/total_streams <= .1
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the RDBMS that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: SQL Server has `SELECT TOP (top_value) [ PERCENT ]`

Answer (score 0):

You method is fine with one caveat.  The `count(distinct)` is not necessary -- and probably hurts performance:

```
select s.*
from (select stream_id, sum(stream_rev) as rev,
             rank() over (order by sum(stream_rev) desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) as cnt
      from mastertable
      where quarter = '2019-Q4'
      group by stream_ID
     ) s
where seqnum <= 0.1 * cnt
```